# Passing Worksheet To Sub Routine

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to call a sub routine by passing a certain sheetname as the parameter, but I receive the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub PerformanceLeague()

Dim wsPerformanceLeague As Worksheet

Set wsPerformanceLeague = Worksheets("PerformanceLeague")
SetHeadings wsPerformanceLeague

End Sub

Public Sub SetHeadings(sSheet As Worksheet)

Dim headers() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

I have tried calling the sub routine as below as well, but receive the same error:

```
Call SetHeadings(wsPerformanceLeague)
```

Comment: `wsPerformanceLeague = Worksheets("PerformanceLeague")` change it to `Set wsPerformanceLeague = Worksheets("PerformanceLeague")`

Comment: Also declare it at `Dim wsPerformanceLeague  as Worksheet`

Comment: Can you tell us in which line you are receiving that error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Declare `wsPerformanceLeague` as worksheet. `Dim wsPerformanceLeague as Worksheet`
2. Change `wsPerformanceLeague = Worksheets("PerformanceLeague")` to `Set wsPerformanceLeague = Worksheets("PerformanceLeague")`

You have to use the word `Set`

Comment: I have updated the code to match this but i get a new error, will update the main post

Comment: Hope you deleted the line `Global wsPerformanceLeague As Worksheet`?

Comment: Yes, Global line removed as well